# SQ Lite insert just a single identifier

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, syntax-error, identifier

I have the following table in my database

```
" CREATE TABLE Q_GROUP ( Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ); "
```

This is only needed to ensure different Items are in the same group. Each time, when adding new items, I need to create a unique group. The items are then connected to this group. The usual syntax for adding items and auto-incrementing the identifier is to specify the items but not the identifier. In this case, sq lite gives a syntax error when attempting this.

Should I add a foo value to the table, or is there a better way to do this in SQ Lite?

-- edit --

The following queries give a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO Q_GROUP VALUES;
INSERT INTO Q_GROUP VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Q_GROUP () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Q_GROUP ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `null` as placeholder

```
insert into Q_GROUP (Id) 
values (null);
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c8fda/1)

Answer (score 2):

try like this,

```
insert into Q_GROUP values(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert the default values in all columns, use:

```
INSERT INTO Q_GROUP DEFAULT VALUES;
```